# Creating a multiline div with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to make a function that creates divs containing text and puts them in another div called "history".

The problem is that the text in the divs come out as single lines like this

2/2=1
instead of this 
2/2

=1
It may also be caused by the height limitation of the div, if so how do I automatically adjust the size with javascript.

```
function creatediv() {
  var element = document.createElement("div");
  var doc = "2/2" + "\n" + "=1";
  const es = element.style;
  element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(doc));
  document.getElementById('history').appendChild(element);
  es.backgroundColor = "azure";
  es.margin = "3px"
  es.borderRadius = "5px";
  es.padding = "2px"
}
```

Comment: Use `white-space: pre;`.

Comment: Or use an html line break `<br/>` instead of `\n` and set innerHTML

Comment: I ran your code and it outputs everything on a single line. I would assume that the text doesn't have enough width in your application, `white-space:no-wrap` would help force it stay on one line might cause overflow though

Comment: @ZohirSalak I think you read the question backwards. OP is expecting the ``\n`  to display as multi line

Comment: wow, i should probably go lay down for a minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use the CSS property `white-space: pre` which makes line-breaks (and other whitespace) inside HTML `#text` nodes visible.
- `white-space` is exposed in the DOM as `CSSStyleDeclaration.whiteSpace`.

  - Values are set as normal strings, e.g. `'pre'` or `'normal'`.
  - e.g.: `document.getElementById('abc123').style.whiteSpace = 'pre';`
- You don't need `element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(doc));`, you can set `.textContent` directly.

Like so (click "Run code snippet"):

```js
function createDiv() {

    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.textContent = "2/2\n=1";

    const s = div.style;
    s.backgroundColor = "azure";
    s.margin          = "3px";
    s.borderRadius    = "5px";
    s.padding         = "2px";
    s.whiteSpace      = 'pre';  // <-- Right here.

    document.getElementById('history').appendChild( div );
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="createDiv()">Create DIV</button>

<div id="history" style="border: 3px inset #999"></div>
```

Comment: What is that format setting called?

Comment: @MaximilianDolbaum What do you mean by "format setting"?

Comment: that all the equal signs are below each other, if you didn't manually do it, it looks kinda neat

Comment: @MaximilianDolbaum That is entirely coincidental.